# Jumping to a selected object with mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, view

Apologies if this has already been asked -
I'm creating a solar system model in Unity 3D, and so far I'm able to orbit an object when the main camera is target object is selected before hitting play. I would like to know I could click on any of the other planets and be able to at least jump to another planet whilst in play mode.
Here's my mouse orbit view currently
[Mouse orbit view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHs6g.jpg)

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail, it is not very clear what you need :)

Comment: For moving camera you can use "MoveTowards()" function - if you want to know about clicking on other planets maybe you can read about "RayCast" in unity :)

Comment: It looks like ray cast is what I might need - what I am trying to do is get the camera to move to another planet when I click on that planet.

Comment: You can read more about Raycasting here: https://gamedevacademy.org/learn-and-understand-raycasting-in-unity3d/#Raycasting_in_3D - and also for moving the camera check out this thread: https://answers.unity.com/questions/808856/move-camera-towards-object.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a raycast from your camera to your mouse position (use Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).
If your raycast hits an object you can set your camera position in relation to that selected object and set your target accordingly.